# php curl post to pingdom not working

Tags: php, post, curl, pingdom

Trying to post a url to pingdom's web page load testing tool, and grab the resulting html...but, all I get is the home page, as though the post hasn't even gone through. Can anybody see what's going wrong here?

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
$data = array('testurl'="www.google.ca");


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
echo curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Comment: Are you even allowed to do that?

Comment: Why wouldn't I be? It's free to use normally

Comment: Are you trying to use the API?

Comment: Most services don't like to be leeched.

Comment: No, what you see is what you get...not using any other code but this.

Answer (score 3):

Why would you expect anything else?  The home page is all that is there.

If you are trying to get results, you need to look again at how this site works.  They are loading results dynamically, with AJAX.

Comment: I see...so...how would I view these results using PHP? I just need the HTML the ajax is returning

Comment: Download a copy of Fiddler or Wireshark and watch what happens.  You'll see a hit to http://browserapi.pingdom.com/api/0.1/test with a few parameters.  That's what you want to emulate.

Comment: Lol I have...I can't figure out the damn API...I only see API for their monitoring tool not for page load test tool

Comment: So posting to browserapi.pingdom.com.api/0.1/test ... how do I know what parameters to pass?

Comment: @valen, If you can't figure out the two parameters you need (test_id, poll_state_url), then you really shouldn't be attempting this at the moment.  Learn to use the tools I suggested, and fully understand how their site works.  If you cannot find published API information, it's probably because they don't want you using their API.

Comment: Where did...you...find those o.O?

Comment: @valen, Are you even listening to me?  How do you think I found them?  Oh gee, I don't know, maybe I **used the tools I suggested to you**.

Comment: @Brad Sorry I mean to say...The whole purpose of hitting their homepage with this request is to obtain the test_id and poll_state_url, so that I can programatically test web pages and view the resulting har files. My question is how to obtain the test_id and poll_state_url

Comment: @valen I tend to say: do your own research. I won't, but I am thinking it.

Comment: Thanks PeeHaa. I have been...and I will continue to do so. I'm new to curl and APIs in general, so please excuse my ignorance

Comment: @valen, Are you even listening to me? How do you think I found them? Oh gee, I don't know, maybe I used the tools I suggested to you. – Brad 4 mins ago